# Tradução de "Lead" no contexto de vendas

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Em inglês, *Sales Lead* ou só *Lead* é uma espécie de potencial venda. Por exemplo, se eu sou vendedor de aspiradores e arranjo o contacto de uma empresa que precisa de comprar aspiradores, por exemplo, isso é uma *Lead*.

Em português, que termo(s) melhor designa(m) ou traduz(em) este conceito?

- venda potencial?
- oportunidade?
- oportunidade de venda?

Nenhuma delas soa muito bem. Certamente, num contexto de vendas, os falantes de português usam algum termo para se referirem a este conceito, mas qual?

Comment: Não me lembro de ver "lead" sendo traduzido — onde quer que tenha visto, vi o termo em inglês. Você talvez tenha de traduzir, mas, dependendo do contexto, pode ser razoável usar a palavra em inglês como jargão.

Answer (score 2):

Os termos equivalentes em português são ***manifestação de interesse*** ou ***contato***, ou seja é uma pessoa ou entidade que contata a empresa manifestando interesse nos seus produtos. Uma *lead* não é bem nem uma *venda potencial* nem uma *oportunidade de venda*; vejamos o que diz a [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sales-lead.asp):

> A sales lead is a prospective consumer of a product or service, created when an individual or business shows interest and provides contact information. […] a sales lead is not a sales prospect; further qualification of the lead is necessary to determine intent and interest.

O resto do artigo explica que a *lead* é uma mera ‘manifestação de interesse’. Por exemplo alguém contata a pedir informação sobre o produto ou deixa o email, clica num botão e aceita receber uma newsletter sobre o teu produto. Depois é necessário ‘qualificar’ esta ‘manifestação de interesse’: indagar para saber se a pessoa está mesmo interessada em comprar, ou se foi só curiosidade ou se nem sabia muito bem no que é que estava a clicar quando aceitou receber a newsletter. Depois deste trabalho de ‘qualificação’ é que algumas ‘leads’ se revelam oportunidades de venda.

Em Portugal encontra-se ***manifestação de interesse*** usado explicitamente como equivalente a *lead* (e foi o termo que me indicou um colega professor de marketing; ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> Um **lead** é um **contato** ou uma **manifestação de interesse** que pode culminar numa oportunidade de negócio e, em último caso, numa venda.
>   [[“Mas afinal o que faz uma agência de Marketing Digital?”, Outmarketing (Portugal)]](http://www.outmarketing.pt/blog/mas-afinal-o-que-faz-uma-agencia-de-marketing-digital/)
>
> – O Desejo que a nossa Campanha de Marketing Digital gera nos consumidores poderá ser medido através do CPL (Custo Por **Lead (manifestação de interesse)**).
>   [[Utilizar o Método AIDA para medir o retorno de campanhas de Marketing Digital, Blog Joãobem.biz (Portugal)]](http://www.joaobem.biz/blog/utilizar-o-metodo-aida-para-medir-o-retorno-de-campanhas-de-marketing-digital/)

No Brasil não encontrei esta equivalência explícita, mas encontrei *lead* associado a *manifestação de interesse*:

> Todo o gerenciamento dos contatos dos interessados na franquia e dos **leads** é feito por uma executiva que conta exclusivamente com a ajuda de um sistema online que permite acompanhar o candidato desde a **manifestação de interesse** até o fechamento do contrato.
>   [[*Lições do Franchising da Terra do Tio Sam*, Bittencourt (Brasil)]](http://www.bittencourtconsultoria.com.br/artigos/licoes-do-franchising-da-terra-do-tio-sam.html)

***Contato*** é mais vago que *manifestação de interesse*, de modo que para ser usado precisará do contexto para esclarecer exatamente do que se trata. Eis um exemplo:

> **Geração de contatos** ou "**lead generation**" é um termo utilizado a partir dos anos 80, em marketing, para designar a atividade ou processo de gerar contato entre os seus clientes potenciais e sua empresa.
>   [...]
>   Um **contato**, dentro deste conceito de marketing, é a ação de um cliente potencial em busca de informações ou de **manifestação de interesse** de compra.
>   [[*Gerando Contatos*, Merkatus (Brasil)]](http://merkatus.com.br/10_boletim/221.htm)

Por outro lado, *contato* é mais flexível: pode ser interpretado como o contato que o consumidor potencial efetua, manifestando interesse, como na citação acima; ou como a informação para contato,—nome, telefone, email, etc.; ou ainda como a própria pessoa que contatou.

Mas na verdade o que é mesmo mais usado em português parece ser *lead*. Por exemplo existe um [artigo sobre *geração de leads* na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_lides) que usa apenas *lead* (exceto no título, onde usa *lide*; coisa que não aconselho porque [*lide* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lide) é outra coisa). E se googlares [*angariação de leads*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22angaria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20leads%22&oq=%22angaria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20leads%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30k1.30569.39227.0.39961.5.5.0.0.0.0.99.392.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.5.389...0i8i30k1j0i7i30k1.OWXd--b_pMI) obténs montes de resultados, enquanto [*angariação de manifestações de interesse*](https://www.google.pt/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22angaria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20manifesta%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20de%20interesse%22&oq=%22angaria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20manifesta%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20de%20interesse%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.16857j0j7) dá só um.

Comment: Sim, também já ouvi o uso da palavra *Lead* mesmo em português, como tantos "inglesismos" nós usamos ao falar português. O "vamos ao shopping", "fazer topless", "beber iogurtes Light", "fazer zoom na máquina fotográfica", etc.. E *Lead* soa muito melhor do que *oportunidade* ou outra qualquer. O problema é que nem toda a gente conhece o significado de *Lead*. Estava curioso para ver se em português existiria alguma palavra simples como *Lead* para definir esse conceito

Comment: @chiapa *Lead* ou os equivalentes em português, *manifestação de interesse* ou *contacto*, são termos técnicos da área do marketing. Eu não esperaria que o leigo conhecesse qualquer destes termos (eu não conhecia, mesmo convivendo bastante com pessoal da área do marketing). Imagino que a maioria do pessoal de língua inglesa também não conheça este sentido de *lead*. Mas em contexto, *manifestação de interesse* compreende-se: «a campanha de marketing na net começou ontem, e já temos 80 manifestações de interesse».

Answer (score 1):

Procurar compradores em potencial faz parte das funções de muitos vendedores. Em pt-BR eu, pessoalmente, usaria o termo  "identificar e contactar potenciais compradores"  Em um jargão mais especializado, do "marketing" por exemplo, usa-se o termo **mercado-alvo**.

- **identificando e contactando o mercado-alvo**
- **identificando e abordando potenciais compradores**

> O mercado é uma instituição social que estabelece as condições para a troca de bens e serviços. No mercado, os vendedores e os compradores criam uma relação comercial para desenvolver transacções, trocas ou acordos.
>   Pode-se dizer que, para além do espaço físico, o mercado surge ou se materializa no momento em que os vendedores se relacionam com os compradores e se articula um mecanismo de procura e oferta.
>   **A noção de mercado-alvo diz respeito ao destinatário ideal de um produto ou serviço. O mercado-alvo, por conseguinte, é o sector da população ao qual se destina um bem.**  As variáveis mais habituais para determinar um mercado-alvo são a idade, o género e as condições socioeconómicas. Por exemplo: uma empresa planeia lançar no mercado uma nova linha de sapatilhas de futebol. O mercado-alvo, neste caso, será composto por homens com menos de 50 anos, uma vez que se entende que este tipo de sapatilhas é adequado a pessoas de género masculino e que estejam em condições de realizar actividades desportivas.
>
> Uma boneca, no entanto, terá como mercado-alvo as meninas com idade inferior ou igual a 12 anos. Nenhum fabricante tentará seduzir ou atrair outro tipo de comprador, pois, segundo a lógica comercial, nenhuma mulher de 30 anos ou jovem de 21 anos terá interesse em comprar uma boneca (a menos que seja para oferecer a uma criança).
>   **Para definir o mercado-alvo, é necessário analisar o comportamento dos consumidores.** A partir de então, sim, fica-se a saber que tipo de público visar e que campanhas de marketing são mais adequadas para posicionar o produto.

[**mercado-alvo**](http://conceito.de/mercado-alvo)

Comment: Acho que uma *lead* não é um mercado-alvo. O mercado-alvo seriam todas e quaisquer empresas que usem aspiradores, e a *lead* seria uma empresa concreta (e.g. Armazéns Poeirentos S.A.) que está a precisar de comprar aspiradores agora, e a quem o vendedor está (ou vai estar) a prestar particular atenção e esforço. Uma "dica" poderia ser uma *lead*.

Comment: @ANeves   Minha resposta para "sales lead" não foi "mercado-alvo".   Foi, sim, "identificando e contactando o mercado-alvo" ou "identificando e abordando potenciais compradores"

Comment: Ah, agora percebo melhor... não me leves a mal, é que à segunda-feira o meu cérebro não funciona a 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Um (sales) lead em inglés é um cliente potencial. Funciona assim o termo:
Por exemplo, você trabalha com vendas, então você mantem uma lista de nomes de pessoas e/ou companhias que poderiam se interessar em comprar o seu produto. Isso se chama a list of sales' leads: uma lista de clientes potenciais.

Normalmente, a ideia é ligar para essas pessoas ou envia-lhes emails (o cartas) ou seja fazer marketing dirigido a elas para "levantar" ou conseguir vendas).

O sentido de potencial é que fulano virará cliente. Se usa a palavra lead porque lead quer dizer lever ou conduzir, a ideia sendo que o contato leverá ou conduzirá à um cliente novo. Também tem uma relação indireta com o trabalho que faz um detetive: to follow a lead. Seguir uma pista.